# Quickly find an entity in VS 2010 EDM Designer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-4

Whenever I need to check something in VS 2010 EDM designer I face the same problem: It takes me sometimes five minutes to find the entity I'm looking for, if the model contains 20+ entities with relations.

I'm wondering is there some way for me to quickly find the entity by name in EDM designer (some add-on, hidden key sequence, rain-dance, anything really...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Model Browser tool window (Ctrl + 1, I think).

Then expand the Entity Types node and right-click on an entity -> choose "Show in designer"

Comment: Ty, I tried double-clicking the entity in Model Browser, but didn't try "Show in designer". A bit counter-intuitive but better than nothing. :)

Comment: Works perfectly on my EDM with 200 entities!